# Get (SSO - Single Sign On)vcenter user information and change password through api or sdk with nodejs

Tags: node.js, vmware, vsphere, node-vsphere

We have a vmware vsphere vcenter at our workplace with about 50 users. We are planning to create an application through which users can view their password expiration time without logging in to the vcenter environment and change their password right there.
I was able to login through the api and get the token but I couldn't find a way to get the user information.
Through this library([node-vsphere-soap](https://github.com/reedog117/node-vsphere-soap)), I could only get the full name of the user.
We really need to create this app and I would be grateful if anyone can help or guide me if they have similar experience.

Get user information and change password

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.